# Can't change MAC address in registry with batch file in Win 10 (but can manually)?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I can succesfully change the MAC address of my wifi-adapter by going to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0002` in the registry, manually change the value of `NetworkAddress` and reboot the wifi-adapter (disable... enable).

However, if I use this batch script (run as administator)...

`netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" Disable
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0002" /v NetworkAddress /t REG_SZ /d 1234567890 /f
netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" Enable`

(in stead of 1234567890 I use a valid MAC)

...then in the registry I can see that the value `NetworkAddress` has changed, but (after rebooting the wifi) the wifi **doesn't** use the changed MAC, but uses the original MAC!?

If I use Technitium MAC Address Changer, it seems to do exactly the same as what I try to do with my batch-file, but somehow **does** work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (someone please correct me if I'm wrong). Afaik the MAC address is part of the hardware of the adapter. Windows copies it to the registry at boot time to "have it ready". I'm quite sure, your Addres Changer tool does not (only) change the registry value, but (also) changes the address directly at the adapter. (just a note to anyone: don't mess with the MAC address, until you are very sure, what you do and what the consequences are)

Answer (score 0):

Ok very strange but the following **does** work:

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0002" /v NetworkAddress /t REG_SZ /d 112233445566 /f
netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" Disable
netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" Enable`

Even the `/t REG_SZ` can be left out.

(instead of 112233445566 I use a valid mac)